# JPA query not fetching results

Tags: jpa

i am working on a certain project. I have a JPA query, which i want to give me a result set but the result has to exclude entries matching some data in another table thus am using NOT IN. My query is as below:

```
String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(tia.voucherId) As Voucher, "
                    + "e.farmId.name As Farm, CONCAT(e.farmId.farmerId.firstName, ' ', e.farmId.farmerId.lastName) AS Farmer,"
                    + " tia.seasonId.name Season, e.farmingActivityId.name As FarmingActivity FROM Enrollment e,"
                    + " TemporaryInputsAllocated tia where e.farmId = tia.farmId"
                    + " AND tia.voucherId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(ia.voucherId) from InputsAllocated ia )";
```

When i run my code i get the error:

```
 ERROR controllers.ContractApplicationController  - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT DISTINCT(tia.voucherId) As Voucher, e.farmId.name As Farm, CONCAT(e.farmId.farmerId.firstName, ' ', e.farmId.farmerId.lastName) AS Farmer, tia.seasonId.name Season, e.farmingActivityId.name As FarmingActivity FROM Enrollment e, TemporaryInputsAllocated tia where e.farmId = tia.farmId AND tia.voucherId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(ia.voucherId) from InputsAllocated ia )], line 1, column 333: unexpected token [(].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(83@[1302:1: simpleSelectExpression returns [Object node] : (n= singleValuedPathExpression | n= aggregateExpression | n= variableAccessOrTypeConstant );])
```

Comment: Why have you got `DISTINCT(ia.voucherId)` when it should be `DISTINCT ia.voucherId` ? The message tells you where the problem is ... char 333. And is this supposed to be SQL or JPQL? you say it is for JPA, but then label the variable as "sql"

Comment: BTW `DISTINCT` is useless in a subquery with `IN`